# Calling stored procedure in DBT and storing it into a temp table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

How can I call snowflake stored procedure in dbt which can then be inserted into a temp table. Snowflake stored proc returns 250 columns. I need to store these in temporary table to do a merge further on a prod table.